# Activity indicator inside an alert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to add an activity indicator as a part of an alert? I need this because it is difficult to show alert view in white background. Please suggest ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually searching for progress dialog... loading indicator + message............